# JFET source follower input impedance without gate resistor

Tags: transistors, bandwidth

I am trying to do a high bandwith and high imput impedance analog front end for a mini oscilloscope project. I am using a JFET for this purpose. I accounter a weird behaviour and i don't understand it.

When i applied 50Hz, 2Vpp square wave to the input of the source follower when the gate resistor is 4M ohm I get results below both in simulation and on the circuit.

[image]

But when I remove the gate resistor low frequency response gets very nice both in simulation and on circuit. I belive this is not proper usage of JFETs but I don't understant the behaviour. Do you know the cause for this?

When diodes revomed results are still same.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With no resistor, there is nothing to set the DC voltage on the gate. It is still AC coupled to the input.

A JFET's gate is actually a pn junction, so leakage currents (<< nA) will eventually cause the gate to charge up, but this could take many minutes and will depend on the leakage on your capacitor and/or the other diodes you have connected. You will need a resistor to set the gate DC bias voltage.

Comment: if I periodically clear the charged voltage from gate pin after each sampling, with a relay or analog multiplexer is it usable or will there be other problems?

Comment: Yes, that would work, but might give unexpected outputs on your waveform. You should also use a larger capacitor (10's of uF) to give a longer time constant.  Why are you AC-coupling the input anyway ?

Comment: I want both ac and dc coupling capability so there is another path with an opamp which does dc coupling. But when i feed gate with dc coupling i couldnt solve the oscillation and setling time problems.

Comment: so just use DC coupling and eliminate the capacitor.

Comment: main opamps input bias current is high so i can not get 1Mohm input impedance with it.